# Difference between "diskutil unmount" and "diskutil unmountDisk"?

Tags: disk-utility, mount, diskutil

Sometimes when I try to unmount a disk using the "diskutil" command I get the following message:

```
$ diskutil unmount /dev/disk1
disk1 was already unmounted or it has a partitioning scheme so use "diskutil unmountDisk" instead
```

when I replace "unmount" with "unmountDisk" it works perfectly fine.

So my question is, **what's the difference between the "unmount" and "ummountDisk" commands?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From `man diskutil`:

```
 unmount | umount [force] device
     Unmount a single volume.  Force will force-unmount the volume (less kind to any open
     files; see also umount (8)).

 unmountDisk | umountDisk [force] device
     Unmount an entire disk (all volumes).  Force will force-unmount the volumes (less kind
     to any open files; see also umount (8)).  You should specify a whole disk, but all
     volumes of the whole disk are attempted to be unmounted even if you specify a parti-
     tion.
```

So `diskutil unmount` just ejects a single volume/partition, `diskutil unmountDisk` the whole disk (including all volumes/partitions).

Comment: Makes sense, the disk I was attempting to eject contained multiple volumes. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You are using the command incorrectly. When issuing `diskutil unmount`, you should refer to a partition. You are referring to an entire disk. For example `disk0` refers to the entire disk, where as, `disk0s1` refers to partition 1 on disk 0. The letter `s` stands for slice which is another word for partition.

On the other hand, it is Ok to refer to either the entire disk or just a partition when trying to unmount an entire disk. So

```
diskutil unmountdisk /dev/disk0s1
```

would be equivalent to

```
diskutil unmountdisk /dev/disk0
```

Both unmount the entire `disk0`.